# Display Content div onclick of nav item

Tags: javascript

Question : Beginner Level
Code: Pure Javascript

I had created a web page in which i am rendering the main nav items via a for loop in javascript. Below the main nav i had created some content assigned each main content div with different ids.

Now i want onclick of any nav item, respective content div should be displayed. please find the jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/shabirgilkar/GKLJz/1/

May i know how to do that in pure javascript. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does it mean then i shouldn't get the answer...??

Comment: no, it means nobody will bother to answer your question ;-)

Comment: you see? so easy question and no answer in 22 minutes, normaly it would take like 2 minutes, its like one line of js code...

Comment: Let you answer then...When u r spending time to track my question.

Comment: ok, I answered then! :-) just accept correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GKLJz/3/

The trick is that you assign ids to menu items in your array and than you call `onClick` function that switches css classes accordig to what you click on...

And if you want to make it pretty, use some js animation effect instead of changing classes, like jQuery slide described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590403/jquery-how-make-div-slide-in-and-out)

Btw you can ommit init() function entirely an just assign `.hidden` to other divs as default

Answer (score 1):

Provided your text inside the navigation boxes match the id of the div.contents This code should work.
Hope i helped.

```
old="home";
        function init() {
            document.getElementById('about').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('products').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('services').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('career').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('faq').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('contact').style.display = 'none';
        var pages = document.querySelectorAll('a.box');
        for(i=0;i<pages.length;i++){
          pages[i].onclick=function(e){
              document.getElementById(old).style.display='none';
              old=e.target.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
              document.getElementById(old).style.display='inline-block';
              }
        }
            }
```