# How can I make a menu that makes the browser window slide to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, so here is the effect I am attempting to emulate:

http://www.lukestevenson.me/

http://sohacks.com/

Notice how when a menu item is clicked on, the menu slides to the appropriate div. How can I do this with my menu? My website is at willowlake.github.io .

Thanks.

**EDIT :** Thanks guys! Don't waste any more of your time on this simpleton question, it has been answered in depth.

Comment: goodness me......have you even tried googling before asking this super basic question????

Comment: Yes, I must not be looking in the right places or using the right keywords because I've not been able to find anything on the topic. The keyword here is "slide", not simply link to.

Comment: http://www.paulund.co.uk/smooth-scroll-to-internal-links-with-jquery OR https://www.google.de/search?q=smooth+slide+to+a+div+when+clicked+on+the+related+menu&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=7PTMUrGZHYiShgfX7oCIDg#channel=fflb&q=smooth+slider+to+a+div+when+clicked+on+the+related+menu&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&safe=off&spell=1

Comment: Thanks! I know I probably should learn to use Google better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

[How can I make a DIV slide in and out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590403/how-can-i-make-a-div-slide-in-and-out)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

Tiny Scrolling is a small script dedicated to support the navigation between the internal links and their destinations.
It replace that annoying and confusing jump from various part of a page with a smooth scroll of the page itself.

[Download the script (.js)](http://www.centralscrutinizer.it/en/download/tinyscrolling.js)

[Tiny Scrolling](http://lab.centralscrutinizer.it/the-tiny-scrollings/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `script` and you will be able to get the effect.

```
$('#idOfYourMenuItem').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#idOfYourDiv').offset().top });
});
```