# Menu Item Issue

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am working on a site where I want to tweak the menu items. For some reasons when click on the menu items it doesn't direct to the relevant portion as it should be(the attached images describes it very well). What I want is, it should direct to the exact top of the portion when clicked.

(*Currently it works wrong)*  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NutST.png

 *(It should work like this)* https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6BgC.png

You can visit the site here http://goo.gl/LhHuHP.

Any reply would be appreciable

Comment: This is not in `java`

Comment: @user3093626 : Java is different from Javascript or Jquery :p

Comment: please post relevant code here....

Comment: I have posted the site link in above post you can compile the code from there; http://goo.gl/LhHuHP

Comment: I'm not able to open the link provided,Is this the same thing you are asking about?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988740/how-can-i-make-a-menu-that-makes-the-browser-window-slide-to-a-div/20989150#20989150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the header height is `85px` But you have given `115px` padding in `script.js`. Changing it to `85px` would fix this issue.

Find this line in `script.js`

```
pos.top -= 115;
```

change it to

```
pos.top -= 85;
```

Adjust the number if you still having spacing problems.

Comment: Thanks dear, that's seems the solution I was looking for but can your please send me the exact js link where I can find this code?

Comment: This is your path `http://winning.winningsites.com.au/wp-content/themes/sonnewtp/js/scripts.js

Answer (score 0):

When you open your site, you must have a margin for the top (header) section. when you click on the menu it keeps that value..  You could try to insert onclick event for that "nav" tag to auto change the height..

Answer (score 0):

Your nav href="#our-portfolio" is not proper (Proven) link see my code and try this

```
<li class="active"><a href="#our-portfolio" title="Proven" class="proven">Proven</a></li> /* is your code */

<li class="active"><a href="#proven" title="Proven" class="proven">Proven</a></li> /* this is working properly */
```

Comment: The problem with all menu items not only with "proven". I have posted images links for reference.